# Using mutate to create variables with extra operations in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create a new column called "1adj" from the column "1", which has also used round and mean and minus -100, which I can do:

```
1adj <- round(mean(DF$1)-100)
```

However, I want to do this with multiple DF columns (20-27) using GGplot, using mutate to create them as new columns in the DF. I can create the extra columns:

```
DF<-DF %>%
    mutate(across(20:27,
            .names = "{.col}Adj"))
```

But where would I add the extra parameters as reflected in the first line of code, so I don't have to type them all out? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the function into `across`.

```
library(tidyverse)

DF %>%
    mutate(across(c(2:4),
                  .names = "{.col}Adj", ~ round(mean(
                      .x
                  ) - 100)))
```

Output

```
  id    first   second    third firstAdj secondAdj thirdAdj
1  1 38.99329 42.34167 37.94029      -65       -69      -62
2  2 20.09237 32.93632 47.81479      -65       -69      -62
3  3 37.64040 33.81845 48.85903      -65       -69      -62
4  4 31.46730 21.59382 23.18026      -65       -69      -62
5  5 49.19273 22.81820 29.91952      -65       -69      -62
```

To return only the new values to the global environment, you can subset the dataframe to the 3 values, then use `list2env` to add it to your global environment.

```
DF %>%
  mutate(across(c(2:4),
                .names = "{.col}Adj", ~ round(mean(.x) - 100))) %>%
  select(firstAdj:thirdAdj) %>%
  unique() %>% 
  c() %>%
  list2env(., envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

If you just want to return the values directly to the global environment without the dataframe, then you can do something like this.

```
output <- map(DF[,2:4], function(x) round(mean(x) - 100))
# If you want to change names of the output.
names(output) <- paste0(names(output), "Adj")
list2env(output, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

If you are looking for on a row by row basis, then use `rowwise`.

```
library(tidyverse)

DF %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(across(c(2:4),
                .names = "{.col}Adj", list( ~ round(mean(
                  .x
                ) - 100))))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 7
# Rowwise: 
     id first second third firstAdj secondAdj thirdAdj
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1  39.0   42.3  37.9      -61       -58      -62
2     2  20.1   32.9  47.8      -80       -67      -52
3     3  37.6   33.8  48.9      -62       -66      -51
4     4  31.5   21.6  23.2      -69       -78      -77
5     5  49.2   22.8  29.9      -51       -77      -70
```

Data

```
DF <-
  structure(
    list(
      id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
      first = c(
        38.9932923251763,
        20.0923723727465,
        37.640398349613,
        31.4673039061017,
        49.192731983494
      ),
      second = c(
        42.341671793256,
        32.936319950968,
        33.8184517389163,
        21.5938150603324,
        22.8182014194317
      ),
      third = c(
        37.9402944352478,
        47.8147878032178,
        48.8590325415134,
        23.1802612892352,
        29.9195193173364
      )
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-5L)
  )
```

Comment: Thank you. That seems to work. Can I ask why is rowwise() needed? Is mutate across not sufficient?

Comment: @user15950867 It depends on the exact output you are looking for. Can you edit your question and show what you expect the output to look like? So, should each new column just have the same number? For example, if `rowwise` is not used, then for `firstAdj`, you would get `round(mean(DF$first)-100)`, which would return -65 for all rows in that column. But perhaps that's what you are looking for?

Comment: Okay, that's what I was looking for, but its good to learn how to compute the other score. Thanks again for your time; I am very grateful.

Comment: @user15950867 I've updated the answer to have both, though with the one you were looking for listed first.

Comment: Thanks, I realise this is almost  a couple of weeks old now, but how would I modify the code so they appear only as values in the environment, not as extra columns in the DF?

Comment: @user15950867 I'm not quite sure what you are asking. Are you wanting to just extract the 3 values and put them into a list?

Comment: So they would appear under "Values" in the environment individually i.e.,
firstadj=-65
firstadj=-58
firstadj=-62

rather than as variables in the dataframe, I also meant it to be the column value not the row value so I presume I would use a different command than rowwise?

Comment: @user15950867 I've updated the answer for how you can use `list2env` to put each value into the global environment under values. Don't use the rowwise one; use the first one listed at the top, which is the one that looks at the whole column rather than just on a row.

Comment: Thanks again. Do you know how to add them straight into the global environment without adding them to the data frame initially? So, just perform the original calculation 1adj <- round(mean(DF$1)-100) on each variable in the DF, but add them to the environment not the data frame.

Comment: @user15950867 I have updated the answer that would just ignore doing it over the dataframe and just apply to each column, then you can put the output into the global environment.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. Good luck with your PhD!

Answer (score 1):

Just keep it simple (if per-row value is desired, i.e., no `mean`):

```
df %>% 
    mutate(
        across(-id, ~round(.-100), .names = "{.col}Adj")
    )
  id    first   second    third firstAdj secondAdj thirdAdj
1  1 38.99329 42.34167 37.94029      -61       -58      -62
2  2 20.09237 32.93632 47.81479      -80       -67      -52
3  3 37.64040 33.81845 48.85903      -62       -66      -51
4  4 31.46730 21.59382 23.18026      -69       -78      -77
5  5 49.19273 22.81820 29.91952      -51       -77      -70
```

For mean you just do mean I guess:

```
df %>% 
    mutate(
        across(-id, ~round(mean(.)-100), .names = "{.col}Adj")
    )
  id    first   second    third firstAdj secondAdj thirdAdj
1  1 38.99329 42.34167 37.94029      -65       -69      -62
2  2 20.09237 32.93632 47.81479      -65       -69      -62
3  3 37.64040 33.81845 48.85903      -65       -69      -62
4  4 31.46730 21.59382 23.18026      -65       -69      -62
5  5 49.19273 22.81820 29.91952      -65       -69      -62
```

Thanks @Andrew Gillreath-Brown for providing example data.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask, what does the (.) mean? Is this saying include all values?

Comment: `~(.)` (note the tilde) here is short for `function(.) (.)` i.e., the expression says `function(x) round(mean(x)-100)`. Each column will the be passed through the function according to the `tidyselect` verb used in `across` (`-id` in this case).